# hello world in C without semicolons and without IF/WHILE/FOR statements

Tags: c, puzzle

My friend says it's possible to write a C program that will print "hello world" without `IF/WHILE/FOR` and without semicolons. After minimal research I told her it was not possible. Is it possible?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754493/hello-world-in-c-with-no-semi-colons

Comment: Why would you want to? If your keyboard is missing a semicolon you have deeper problems.

Comment: Sounds like your friend revels in those obfuscated C and PERL competitions?

Comment: @John: For the same reason people write entries for the obfuscated C contest, or write Perl poetry, or do Sudoku.

Comment: If you have a missing key you can `cat` some random C file and cut-and-paste the `;`.

Comment: Can anyone help print it with #PRAGMA?

Comment: @KennyTM, the link is 404 now.

Comment: Now that [codegolf.se] is up, this kind of question should be posted there instead.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I've been trying to find a "portable" way of stealing a semicolon from an include file.  This works under Linux:

```
int main(int ac, char **av)
{
#define typedef
#define uint8_t a[printf("hello world\n")]
#include <stdint.h>
}
```

This causes the one `typedef unsigned char uint8_t` to become my printf.

Another trick that worked was to `#define` away every standard stdint type such that `stdint.h` reduces to a bunch of semicolons.

Both of these fall flat on FreeBSD because it uses private intermediate types (like `__uint8_t`) which means that removing typedef fails in the quoted example and prevents me from successfully removing all non-semicolons in the other case.

It seems like it should be possible to steal a semicolon cleanly from an include file.  Can anyone improve on my attempt?

Comment: +1 for a very unique approach... I like it.

Comment: Doesn't work in Windows (Microsoft C compiler ver. 17)

Comment: #include <stdint.h> it contains many semicolons

Comment: @orionll Works in Winodws! But with MinGW 4.4 :-P

Answer (score 199):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    switch (printf("Hello, world!\n")) {}
}
```

If your friend says "oh, you can't use switch either," then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")]) {}
```

Comment: main() has no return ;-)

Comment: @tur1ng: It doesn't need one.

Comment: @iam: [Rep cap](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work).

Comment: +1, although you forgot a `*` before `argv`. Why does this work?

Comment: This is why I don't like C (or C++ for that matter). How on earth is that legal? :-S

Comment: @Alxandr `printf` returns an integer, so this fixes the length on *argv to the return value by printf.

Comment: @cdhowie Doesn't work: error C2057: expected constant expression (Microsoft C/C++ compiler 17)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: you need a proper C99 compiler.

Answer (score 41):

I'm torn about whether to suggest this because it hinges on the exact wording of the question, but:

```
#error hello world
```

(if nothing else, perhaps it will stave off a followup "how do you print hello world without `main`"...)

Comment: please dont be so hard on yourself

Comment: The main issue with this technique is that it doesn't actually produce a runnable program.  However, it is certainly clever.  And a clever solution is never a bad solution.

Comment: @cdh but you mean to say "i am still king"

Comment: Haha, nah. I upvoted this one too. :)

Comment: Doesn't work on all platforms, but...
`#pragma message("Hello World!")`
Plus, it'll create a runnable program. Just the program won't do anything :).

Answer (score 20):

> it's possible to write a C program that will print "hello world" without IF/WHILE/FOR and without semicolons.

Easy.  Note that C is case sensitive.

```
int main()
{
    if (printf("Hello, World\n")){}
}
```

`if` is a keyword in C, `IF` is not.

Comment: Why the down vote?  I complied to the letter, to the very case of the question.  It seems a bit harsh when the question itself is one of those useless "how can we legally abuse C" questions.

Comment: @JeremyP  I didn't vote other way, but nobody likes a rules lawyer.

Comment: @Dan Neely: What is a rules lawyer?  Let's be honest, the original question is not exactly a serious programming question, so why do people take a tongue in cheek answer seriously and down vote it?

Comment: @jere please refer to my previous comment

Comment: IF/WHILE/FOR are language structs, not keywords.

Comment: @AbuisX IF, WHILE, FOR are nothing to do with C unless you define them.

Answer (score 16):

You could also workaround the limitation like

```
#define X i##f
#define Y whi##le
#define Z f##or
#define W swi##tch
```

Answer (score 15):

What about:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void *HAHA[printf("Hello world!\n")]) {}
```

ain't C cool :)

Comment: could you explain what it is leagal to insert a function call in another function parameter declaration block? I can hardly understand that.

Comment: I would really love to know... :-)

Comment: printf returns an int (a predictable one in this case too), which means that the full definition of the function, is int main(void * HAHA[12]) { } In order to find out that the magic number is 12, you must first execute the printf statement.

Comment: Doesn't work: error C2057: expected constant expression (Microsoft C/C++ compiler 17)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov: you need a proper C99 compiler.

Answer (score 1):

you can use switch statement to get your desire output,here is the code below

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  switch(printf("hello world"))

return 0;
}
```

hope this will help you