# C Code: How does these even work?

Tags: c, puzzle

I just saw this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147836)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")]) {}
```

What this does is print "Hello World!"

But what's actually going on here?

The best I can guess is that it gets compiled and thrown at the top of the execution stack, but the syntax doesn't even look legal to me ...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The code makes use of C99's variable-length array feature, which lets you declare arrays whose size is known only at run-time. `printf` returns an integer equal to the number of characters that were actually printed, so the code prints "Hello, world!" first and uses the return value as the size of `argv`. The `main` function itself does nothing. <del>The actual call to `printf` itself probably goes into the startup code generated by the compiler, which in turn calls `main`.</del>

**Edit:** I just checked the disassembly of the code generated by `gcc` and it appears that the call to `printf` goes inside `main` itself, before any other code.

Comment: The call to `printf` definitely does not go in any pre-`main` startup code.

Comment: @R..: That was just a guess, and the best I can make. Where else could it possibly be executed?

Comment: @R..: Never mind, you're right about that and I answered my own question. :)

Comment: Yep. Conceptually that's where the code takes place too. VLA size expressions for local variables/function arguments are computed at the point the variable is defined, which for arguments is on function entry. Earlier arguments (here, `argc`) are available for use at this point, and later ones are not.

Answer (score 5):

If I figure out how the compiler parsed it, I'll update this, but at least there needs to be no guesswork as to how it compiled:

```
objdump --disassemble /tmp/hello (edited):

080483c4 <main>:
 80483c4:       55                      push   %ebp
 80483c5:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
 80483c7:       83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
 80483ca:       83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
 80483cd:       b8 a0 84 04 08          mov    $0x80484a0,%eax
 80483d2:       89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
 80483d5:       e8 22 ff ff ff          call   80482fc <printf@plt>
 80483da:       c9                      leave  
 80483db:       c3                      ret    
 80483dc:       90                      nop
 80483dd:       90                      nop
 80483de:       90                      nop
 80483df:       90                      nop
```

Since Linux executables are based normally at 0x8048000, the address of the argument to printf is at an offset of 0x00004a0 from the start of the binary:

```
xxd /tmp/hello | grep 00004a0

00004a0: 4865 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72 6c64 210a 0000  Hello, world!...
```

So, the address of the string is pushed, and printf is called with that one arg. Nothing magical at that level, so all the fun stuff was done by gcc.

Answer (score 4):

> `char *argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")])`

`printf()` returns the number of characters printed.

So

> `int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")]) {}`

is equivalent to

> `int main(int argc, char *argv[14]) {}`

plus a call to `printf()` which prints `"Hello World"`

Comment: That's only true if printf succeeds in printing all characters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm no C expert, but it looks like the command line arguments are declared at the same time as `main`.

Comment: No. Prasoon and casablanca have got it.