# Where's g++'s VLA extension?

Tags: c++, g++

My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151115/c-code-how-does-these-even-work) thread.

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")]) {}
```

I accidently saved it as a `*.cpp` file and tried to compile it with `g++`. But I got an error and a warning.

> `error: expected ',' or '...' before 'argv'`
>   `warning: second argument of 'int main(int, char*)' should be 'char **
>   '`

I know the above code is not Standard C++ [size of an array must be a constant expression in C++] but 
I always thought `g++` supports Varible Length Array as an extension. Where am I wrong?

P.S : The above code gets compiled with CLang++

```
C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>type check.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")]) {}
C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>clang++ check.cpp

C:\Users\SUPER USER\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

g++ allows (again, as an extension) VLAs.  I think it just doesn't allow them in parameter lists.  This compiles in g++ 4.4.1.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *array[printf("Hello, world!\n")];
}
```