# what happens when you create an array with non-const length in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

AFAIK this code is not a valid c++ code by standard:

```
int a = 5;
int b[a];
```

but it seems many compilers can compile that code (mostly with warning) and it just behaves as expected. Am I wrong is is it compilers being nice to me?

Comment: exact duplicate: [Dynamic array In Stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204521/dynamic-array-in-stack), [c++ initialize array with declared size as a value of an integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6330695/c-initialize-array-with-declared-size-as-a-value-of-an-integer), ...

Comment: @fmaas: didn't find those questions sorry

Comment: Actually I was aware of them just because I stumbled on this a few days ago by pure coincidence...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is called variable length array (VLA) which is not allowed by Standard C++, any version of C++, though some GCC supports this as an extension.

If you're using GCC, then

- Compile it with `-pedantic` option, you will see warning.
- Compile it with `-pedantic -Werror` option, you will see warning turned into error.

VLA is allowed only by C99, though not by other versions of C.

Comment: Won't `-std=c++98` (or `-std=c++0x` if you're experimenting, rather than writing production code) suffice to suppress support of VLAs in g++?

Comment: @JamesKanze: No. It doesn't. I tried with `-std=c++98`, `-std=c++03`, and `-std=c++0x`, but none of them suppresses VLA in g++. It is weird, though. I'm using MinGw version 4.6.1 :-)

Comment: That sort of surprises me.  But I'll admit that I've never tried it.  (I always compile with `-std=c++98 -pedantic`.  And in C++, I don't use `T[]` very often, either.)

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is being nice. :)

It's actually part of the C standard, and some compilers (like GCC) extend C++ with this feature.

Comment: More specifically and accurately, it is part of C99 Standard.

Answer (score 2):

This is the C99 standards Variable Length Array (or VLA), many compilers that can compile C99, often allow some of its features to be used in non-standard conforming C++ code.

G++ is one of these compilers, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151254/wheres-gs-vla-extension).