# What difference between C and C++ prohibits this eclectic code sample from compiling in the latter?

Tags: c++, c

I was just wondering about the content of question *['Hello, World!' in C without semicolons and without 'if', 'while', or 'for' statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147836/hello-world-in-c-without-semicolons-and-without-if-while-for-statements)*.

The following code worked in C, but not in C++:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[printf("Hello, World!\n")]) {}
```

In C++, I get this error:

```
error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘argv’|
warning: second argument of ‘int main(int, char*)’ should be ‘char **’ [-Wmain]|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 1 warnings ===|
```

Why is it not working in C++?

Comment: @CarlNorum: That's not really the crux of it. In fact, the OP is trying to give it a `char**` (at least once the array decays), but a parsing error means the compiler is misinterpreting.

Comment: That's true, now that I look at it again.  Hooray for VLAs! =)

Comment: What's your compiler version? And are you sure you copied the code properly? I can't reproduce this at all.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Yes I copied the code correctly. I am using codblocks IDE 10.05. When I ran gcc -v on Ubuntu terminal I got the version :gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Certainly with GCC, it [works in C](http://ideone.com/THi07), but [not in C++](http://ideone.com/fFse8)

Comment: @CppLearner: OK; I've reproduced it in GCC 4.5.1 too now, so I guess it's a parse confusion recently introduced. Ultimately, I guess, there's no "right" way to parse this invalid code.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I'm trying to rationalise about _specific_ versions of GCC, as to this _specific_ error message. I concede that my earlier comment was unclear in that regard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because C++ doesn't have any [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) feature.

The `argv` parameter in

`char *argv[printf("Hello, World!\n")]`

is a variable-length array.

The expression that specify the size of the array is

```
printf("Hello, World!\n")
```

The result of this expression is of type `int` and is the number of characters transmitted (or a negative value if there is an error).

An array where the expression in the `[]` is not constant, like in the example the `printf` expression, is a variable-length array. Those arrays also are permitted to be used as the type of a function parameter.

A variable-length array is a feature introduced in C in [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) and has not been introduced in C++.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? It's quite incomplete for a score of seven.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, I'm doing it

Comment: Does C have a variable array feature?? It's a wonder that this actually compiles in C, and I don't think it's standard.

Comment: @ugoren: C99 does. C89/C90 do not. GCC does support them in C++ as an extension; whether or not that would allow this bizarre code to compile I couldn't say. Anyway, I'm tempted to suggest that this is either a loophole in C's VLAs, or a loophole in GCC's implementation, but I couldn't say for sure.

Answer (score 8):

As the error message indicates, `main` expects `char**` for its second argument. However, due to array decay rules, the following are both OK:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv);   // OK
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);  // OK
```

And, in fact, the following is also equivalent because array decay doesn't care about dimensions:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[5]); // OK
```

However, **whereas in C99 arrays may have variable length, this is *not* the case in C++**. So using a non-constant expression for that array dimension — in your case, `printf("Hello world\n")` — is invalid syntax.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[printf("Hello, world!\n")]); // Not OK!
```

This invalid syntax is confusing the parser and causing this misleading error in your compiler.

If you simplify the code slightly to remove the function-call-expression (but still using a non-constant for array bounds) then [you get a far more relevant error message](http://codepad.org/cAhbNyiz):

```
int x = 5;
int main(int argc, char* argv[x]) {}
// error: array bound is not an integer constant
```

Actually, [GCC 4.1.2 gives this useful message for your original code, too](http://codepad.org/obgeHOFz), <strike>so your compiler must be *really* old... either that or your testcase is broken</strike> [despite the far newer GCC 4.5.1 yielding the message you posted](http://www.ideone.com/0RWqf).

Comment: @Keith: Thanks; suppose that's better. Nuked my latest changes, though!

Comment: Whoops, didn't mean to do that.  I got notice that it had been edited, but I canceled my edit and did it again.  I guess we still managed to collide.

Comment: "Array decay rules" would usually refer to the decay/conversion of an array expression to a pointer to its first element ([C99](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.3.2.1p3).  This is a distinct rule applying to parameter declarations, described by the standard as an adjustment rather than a conversion (C99 6.7.5.3p7).

Comment: @Keith: C++ citations please! I'll be happy to change that terminology though; I basically just made it up ^_^

Comment: Neither standard uses the word "decay" for this, but I've most often seen it used to refer to the implicit array-to-pointer conversion; see, for example, question 6.3 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com).  N3290 (the closest thing I have to the C++11 standard) 4.2 [conv.array] says that the conversion *can* happen; 5p8 [expr] says when it's done implicitly.  The parameter adjustment rule is in 8.3.5p5 [dcl.fct].

Comment: @Keith: Then I guess I made up a non-normative term :)

Comment: @KeithThompson *decay* is also used in Peter van der Linden "Expert C Programming" book, but I agree with you the correct word is *conversion*

Comment: Dentists use it sometimes too, so there's precedence.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `char *argv[some_expression]` is a variable-length array, and so when used as a function argument is interpreted as meaning a pointer (just as a fixed-length or unknown-length array does when declaring a function argument).

In C++, variable-length arrays do not exist, so it's not valid. `char * argv[some_constant]` and `char * argv[]`, are both valid, and equivalent to `char ** argv` - but of course none of these can have side effects, and so can't be used to solve that silly exercise.